# Qt: algorithm to rotate and resize a qgraphicslineitem present on a qgraphicsscene

Tags: qt, rotation, resize, qgraphicsitem

Can someone please share the algorithm to rotate and resize a QGraphicsLineItem present on a QGraphicsScene? I wish to be able to click on either end of the line and rotate it while the opposite end automatically becomes the anchor point for rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the solution given below and it works brilliantly!!. The solution is for line rotation only. This solution is provided to me when i posted the question at other Qt platform. All the credit goes to original author who provided the solution to me.

```
    void Line::mousePressEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event ){
    const QPointF pos = event->pos();
    const qreal l1 = QLineF( pos, this->line().p1() ).length();
    const qreal l2 = QLineF( pos, this->line().p2() ).length();
    const qreal threshold = 3.5;    
    if( l1 < l2 and l1 < threshold ){
        _dragIndex = 1;
    } else if ( l2 < l1 and l2 < threshold ){
        _dragIndex = 0;
    } else{
        _dragIndex = -1;
    }
    event->setAccepted( _dragIndex != -1 );
}

void Line::mouseMoveEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event ){
    if( _dragIndex != -1 ){
        const QPointF anchor = _dragIndex == 0 ? this->line().p1() : this->line().p2();
        QLineF ma = QLineF(anchor,event->pos());
        ma.setLength( line().length() );
        const QPointF rotated = anchor + QPointF( ma.dx(), ma.dy() );
        this->setLine( _dragIndex == 0 ? QLineF(anchor,rotated) : QLineF(rotated,anchor) );
    }
}

void Line::mouseReleaseEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event ){
    _dragIndex = -1;
    QGraphicsLineItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Overload `mouseMoveEvent` of your scene. Make sure you are in the initial state, no clicks, nothing. If position is close enough to the ends, set your flag as such.

```
// scene.cpp
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e){
    if(moveToRotate){
        lineItem->rotate(flag, e->pos());
        ...
        return;
    }

    if(isClose(e->pos(), lineItem->firstEnd)
        flag = 1;
    else if(isClose(e->pos(), lineItem->secondEnd)
        flag = 2;
    else 
        flag = 0;
    return;
}
```

2- Overload mouseClickEvent of the scene. If flag is set (1 or 2), get your anchor point. You can overload paint method of lineItem to highlight the end point. Also set firstClick flag.

```
void mouseClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e){ // firstClick happened
    if(flag !=0){ //process click
        firstClick = true;
        paintAnchor = true;
        moveToRotate = true;
    }
    else // neglect click
        return;

    return;
}

// myCustomLineItemclassThatInheritsQGraphicsLineItem.cpp
void paint(... ){
    if(paintAnchor){
        ...
    }
}
```

There are obvious errors, but the general flow should be as such. You may need a signal to connect the boolean to the paint event of another class. You may need to overload mouseReleaseEvent to properly set moveToRotate. And, of course `rotate` and `isClose` methods are yours to be written -maybe even exist in the API.

Just construct the main flowchart, it will help you a lot.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I appreciate it. Similarly could you please let me know algorithm for resizing a line present on the QGrpahicsScreen? the line should be able to resize within the boubdary rect of the screen only.

Comment: simply overload the doubleclick event and use setLine method to visualize the line using scene edge positions - or corners maybe. make sure you pass the event if only doubleclick happens close enough to the line.

Comment: Thanks Canberk.But why do i need to reimplement doubleclick event? I should be able to resize on single click of a line corner and then when I start moving mouse the resize shld begin. The resize should happen to the point where I release the mouse click again. I should be able to resise the line within the bounding rect of screen. Its not necessary that I select the corner and move the mouse till I reach screen boundary. I should be able to relase the mouse click anywhere in the sceen and line should be resize till that point. So what should be the algo to implement this?

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. Its so easy. You just need to check event position in mouseMoveEvent. if event->pos().x() > scene.boundingRect.x()+width { ma = QLineF(anchor, scene.boundingRect.x()+width);} - will make the line move only up to the border. Try to understand the code you are using :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately I did not understand the line resizing algorithm u mentioned. I'm just a beginner in graphics.As per my understanding the event->scenePos().x() should be less than the width of the scene bounding rect for the line to be drawn.

Comment: @Canberk-Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately I did not understand the line resizing algorithm u mentioned. I'm just a beginner in graphics.As per my understanding the event->scenePos().x() should be less than the width of the scene bounding rect for the line to be drawn. I guess the code should be smethg like : if(event->scenePos().x() < scene.boundingRect.x()+width){ ma = QLineF(anchor, event->scenePos()); this->setLine(ma);}

Comment: The code works, the only care we need to take care is the QLineF points should be (anchor,event->pos()) if P1 is anchor. If P2 is anchor then the QLineF points should be (event->pos(), anchor). Btw in my above comments i wrongly mentioned event->scenePos() instead of event->pos(). I believe we operate in line item local coordinate system. Btw do you know how to create Arrow Graphics Item?

Comment: arrow is a triangle; triangle is a polygon: QPolygonF t;
t.append(QPointF(-10.,0));
t.append(QPointF(0.,-10));
t.append(QPointF(10.,0));
t.append(QPointF(-10.,0));
use QGraphicsScene::addPolygon(t) OR QGraphicsPolygonItem class to represent the triangle.

Comment: Do you know how to convert the line end point on which mouse move event pos() is set( this happens when user clicks on P1(0,0) and anchor is P2(x,y)) back to local coordinate sytem. After resizing is finished, the item should again have points like P1(0,0) and P2(x1,y1).